# Leaflet Sleep Option in R

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, leaflet

I have created a Shiny app which includes a wide Leaflet map. When scrolling down the app, the Leaflet clutches on to the mouse and begins to zoom on the map. This is annoying, zooming on the Leaflet should only be possible after having clicked on the map.

An illustration of the issue as well as a solution using a JavaScript can be found [here](http://cliffcloud.github.io/Leaflet.Sleep/). The JavaScript is [here](https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.Sleep/blob/master/Leaflet.Sleep.js).

My question: how do I integrate this solution in my Shiny app? I tried downloading the JavaScript, placing it into my Shiny folder and run the following code without any success:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)

ui <- dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(distable =T),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = T),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      leafletOutput("flightmap", width="100%", height=400),
      tags$head(tags$script(src="Leaflet.Sleep.js"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$flightmap <- renderLeaflet({

    leaflet(coordinates) %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      addMarkers(~LONGITUD, ~LATITUD) 

  })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

I tried to keep the code above to a minimium - it has been cleared from all kinds of inputs/outputs. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This](https://github.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras) is what youre looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can download `leaflet.extras` package which has this functionality. here is the basic example. Note that I added white spacing to test it

```
#devtools::install_github('bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras')

library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

r_colors <- rgb(t(col2rgb(colors()) / 255))
names(r_colors) <- colors()

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      HTML("#mymap{margin-top:500px;margin-bottom:1000px;}")
    )
  ),
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  actionButton("recalc", "New points")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  points <- eventReactive(input$recalc, {
    cbind(rnorm(40) * 2 + 13, rnorm(40) + 48)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%
      addMarkers(data = points()) %>% suspendScroll()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]